# How to transform a MSSQL CTE query to MySQL 5.7?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, mysql-5.7

I have one SQL queries

```
with temp as 
(
select min(ms_date) as start, max(ms_date) as [end], count(sessionid) 'visitor_count',category,convert(varchar, ms_date , 106) 'ms_date'        
from temp_tbltrack  where category =@id         
group by category,convert(varchar, ms_date , 106)
)
select category,ms_date,CASE WHEN datediff(ss,temp.start,temp.[end]) <>0 THEN datediff(ss,temp.start,temp.[end]) ELSE 45 END 'Timespan',visitor_count from temp
order by convert(datetime,ms_date)
```

I converted into Mysql

```
select temp from 
(
select min(ms_date) as start, max(ms_date) as `end`, count(sessionid) 'visitor_count',category,date_format (ms_date , 106) 'ms_date'        
from temp_tbltrack  where category =p_id         
group by category,date_format (ms_date , 106)
)
select category,ms_date,CASE WHEN timestampdiff(ss,temp.start,temp.[end]) <>0 THEN timestampdiff(ss,temp.start,temp.[end]) ELSE 45 END 'Timespan',visitor_count from temp
order by convert(ms_date, datetime);
```

How I convert CTE in Mysql 5.7 version

Comment: Its giving me error in Mysql

Comment: side note: MySQL `CTE` is available from v.8.0 +

Comment: Yes right but I want to use in 5.7 please help on this

Comment: BEGIN
 select 
 category ,
 ms_date,
 case when timestampdiff(ss, start, end) <> 0 
        then timestampdiff(ss,start,end) else 45 end 'Timespan',
 visitor_count 
 from ()
END

ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ss, start, end) <> 0 
        then timestampdiff(ss,start,end) else 45 end 'Time' at line 6

Comment: Tip: When sharing more info or what you have tried so far, edit your post and add instead of comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think a subquery is needed:

```
select category,
       format(ms_date, '%d %b %Y') as ms_date,
       (case when max(ms_date) = min(ms_date)
             then 45
             else timestampdiff(second, min(ms_date), max(ms_date))
        end) as timestamp
       count(sessionid) as `visitor_count`,
from temp_tbltrack 
where category = @id         
group by category, format(ms_date, '%d %b %Y')
order by min(ms_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use subqueries since you can't use cte on your mysql version.

```
select t1.category
    , t1.ms_date
    , case when datediff(ss, temp.start, temp.[end]) <> 0 
        then datediff(ss,temp.start,temp.[end]) else 45 end 'Timespan' 
    , t1.visitor_count
from 
    (select min(ms_date) as start, max(ms_date) as [end], count(sessionid) 'visitor_count', category, cast(ms_date as date) 'ms_date'        
    from temp_tbltrack  where category =@id         
    group by category, cast(ms_date as date)) t1
order by cast(t1.ms_date as datetime)
```

Comment: As far as I know `[end]`as well as `convert(varchar, ms_date , 106)` will throw error in MySQL.

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE `proc_trackingrtt` (p_id longtext)
BEGIN
select t1.category
    , t1.ms_date
    , case when datediff(ss, temp.start, temp.end) <> 0 
        then datediff(ss,temp.start,temp.end) else 45 end 'Timespan' 
    , t1.visitor_count
from 
    (select min(ms_date) as start, max(ms_date) as [end], count(sessionid) 'visitor_count',category,convert(varchar, ms_date , 106) 'ms_date'        
    from temp_tbltrack  where category =p_id         
    group by category,convert(varchar, ms_date , 106))as t1
order by cast(t1.ms_date as datetime)
END

Comment: BEGIN select category , ms_date, case when timestampdiff(ss, start, end) <> 0 then timestampdiff(ss,start,end) else 45 end 'Timespan', visitor_count from () END ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ss, start, end) <> 0 then timestampdiff(ss,start,end) else 45 end 'Time' at line 6 –