# SQL join each row in a table with a one row from another table

Tags: mysql

## The Problem

I have a table `window` with `start` and `end` timestamps. I have another table `activity` that has a `timestamp`. I would like to create a query that:

- For each row in `activity` it joins with a single row from `window`, where the `timestamp` occurs between `start` and `end`, choosing the older `window`.

**Window Table**

| Start | End | ISBN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 | "ABC" |
| 5 | 15 | "ABC" |
| 20 | 30 | "ABC" |
| 25 | 35 | "ABC" |

**Activity Table**

| Timestamp | ISBN |
| --- | --- |
| 7.5 | "ABC" |
| 27.5 | "ABC" |

**Desired Result**

| Start | End | ISBN | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 | "ABC" | 7.5 |
| 20 | 30 | "ABC" | 27.5 |

## The Attempt

My attempt at solving this so far has ended with the following query:

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    test.activity AS a
    JOIN test.`window` AS w ON w.isbn = (
        SELECT
            w1.isbn
        FROM
            test.window as w1
        WHERE a.`timestamp` BETWEEN w1.`start` AND w1.`end`
        ORDER BY w1.`start`
        LIMIT 1
    )
```

The output of this query is 8 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there is guaranteed to be a single oldest window (i.e. no two `Start` times are the same for any ISBN)

```sql
with activity_window as (
  select
    a.`Timestamp`,
    a.`ISBN`,
    w.`Start`,
    w.`End`,
    row_number() over (partition by a.`ISBN`, a.`Timestamp` order by w.`Start`) rn
  from
    `Activity` a
    inner join `Window` w on a.`ISBN` = w.`ISBN` and a.`Timestamp` between w.`Start` and w.`End`
)
select `Start`, `End`, `ISBN`, `Timestamp` from activity_window where rn = 1;
```

Result:

| Start | End | ISBN | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 | ABC | 7.5 |
| 20 | 30 | ABC | 27.5 |

(see [complete example at DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f6757086d3768a39efd6025cd75fab95))

CTEs are available from MySQL 8.0. [Use subqueries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58705059/how-to-transform-a-mssql-cte-query-to-mysql-5-7) when you are still on MySQL 5. Try to avoid table- and column names that are reserved words in SQL (things like `Window`, `Start`, `End` or `Timestamp` are examples for bad name choices).

Keeping an index over `(ISBN, Start, End)` on `Window` (or clustering the entire table that way by defining those three columns as the primary key) helps this query.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I run this query I only receive a single result when I expect two.

Comment: @Poliziano You're right, my bad. I've changed to a solution using a `ROW_NUMBER()`-based approach, try again.

Comment: I'm sorry for taking so long to respond. You're solution is spot on - thank you.