# Get last 6 month sale with 0 values

Tags: mysql

I use the following query to get the sum of last 6 month sales of a database.

```
SELECT
    pharmacy_bulk_issue_details.product_id,
    COALESCE(
        (
            SUM(
                pharmacy_bulk_issue_details.qty - pharmacy_bulk_issue_details.returened_qty
            )
        ),
        0
    ) AS unit_qty,
    DATE_FORMAT(
        pharmacy_bulk_issue.added_time,
        '%Y %M'
    ) AS MONTH
FROM
    pharmacy_bulk_issue_details
LEFT JOIN pharmacy_bulk_issue ON pharmacy_bulk_issue_details.bulk_id = pharmacy_bulk_issue.id
WHERE
    pharmacy_bulk_issue_details.product_id = '00000004357' AND pharmacy_bulk_issue.added_time >= NOW() - INTERVAL '6' MONTH
GROUP BY
    pharmacy_bulk_issue_details.product_id, DATE_FORMAT(
        pharmacy_bulk_issue.added_time,
        '%Y %M'
    )
```

Everything works fine but, suppose there was no sale for the particular item for last month, then the query will not show it as zero for that month. It is just excluded and the result will be 5 rows. How can I get the zero value row for not sold months?

Comment: Use a calendar table.

Comment: What result type does it return?  Is it finding "EMPTY" or "NULL" when it does the ones that return no sales?  If you know what data type it returns you can test for it with your code and convert it to an Integer, so when IsNULL = TRUE or variable = "" then Variable = CINT(variable)  Convert Empty and NULL type to 0 and then work from there.

Comment: @easleyfixed it returns only 5 rows. Means no row at all for the month of no sales

Answer (score 0):

A calendar table could look like this (considering you are grouping on month):

```sql
WITH recursive calendar as (
   select min(pharmacy_bulk_issue.added_time) as d 
   from pharmacy_bulk_issue_details

   union all

   select date_add(d, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
   from calendar 
   where d <= (select max(pharmacy_bulk_issue.added_time) as d 
               from pharmacy_bulk_issue_details)
)
select * from calendar;
```

**EDIT**:
There is a way to do that, besides updating, see: [How to transform a MSSQL CTE query to MySQL 5.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58705059/how-to-transform-a-mssql-cte-query-to-mysql-5-7)

```sql
set @r=0;

select (SELECT DATE_ADD(MIN(added_time), INTERVAL -DAY(MIN(added_time))+1 DAY)
        FROM pharmacy_bulk_issue) as d
union 
  
SELECT DISTINCT DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(added_time, INTERVAL R MONTH),  INTERVAL -DAY(added_time)+1 DAY) as d
from pharmacy_bulk_issue
cross join (select @r:=@r+1 as R from information_schema.tables t) x
where date_add(added_time, INTERVAL R MONTH) < (SELECT MAX(added_time) 
                                                FROM pharmacy_bulk_issue);
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/UiyKKGtE)

Comment: I'm working in a bit older MYSQL server. It's 5.7.39. So i think this will not work there. Isn't it?

Comment: I added an example of (a working version) in 5.7